# Returning string from C++ function with ctypes gives large int, not char pointer

Tags: python, c++, string, dll, ctypes

I am trying to call C++ functions from a dll using ctypes in python. My current issue is the function seems to return a large int, either positive or negative, instead of the char pointer I expect it to. If I convert that int to a c_char_p and call .value on it, it kills my kernel every single time. I've looked all over this site and in the docs too and can't figure this out. A lot of the things I have seen on this site even throw errors for me, like passing in strings to ctypes opjects and functions when they should be byte objects or something similar. Below is my c++ code that is turned into a dll and the python code I am using to call functions from the dll. Please if anyone can help me, that would be awesome. SaySomething is the function in question. Thanks.

## TestLibrary.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef TESTLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define TESTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    TESTLIBRARY_API char* SaySomething(const char* phrase);

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

## TestLibrary.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>

TESTLIBRARY_API char* SaySomething(const char* phrase)
{
    char* p = new char [100];
    p = "string something";
    return p;
}
```

## tester2.py

```
import ctypes

dbl = ctypes.c_double
pChar = ctypes.c_char_p
pVoid = ctypes.c_void_p

libName = (r"D:\Documents\Coding Stuff\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestLibrary"
           r"Solution\x64\Debug\TestLibrary.dll")
x = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(libName)

x.SaySomething.argtypes = [pChar]
x.SaySomething.restypes = pChar

phrase = b"Hi"
phrase = pChar(phrase)

res = x.SaySomething(phrase)
```

Comment: A C function returns a single value with a single type. It's `restype`, not `restypes`.

Comment: Note also that in your c++ function, ```p = "string something";``` probably won't do what you think. Surprisingly, the result will look like it works ;)

Comment: @ddbug, until you try to modify it (e.g. set `SaySomething.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` and then modify `res[0] = b'x'`). Most compilers put string-literal constants in memory that's mapped read-only, in which case the latter will crash Python.

Comment: Another unrelated problem is that the definition of `TESTLIBRARY_API` uses `dllexport` when `TESTLIBRARY_EXPORTS` isn't defined. It should be `dllimport`. This doesn't affect using the library via ctypes. It's a problem for C/C++ users of the library.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of the OP's previous question, with slightly different code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45146021/235698, but can't mark it as a duplicate because the other has no answer yet either.

Comment: @eryksun why your comment is directed at me? The OP's py code example does not do with res anything at all. Maybe all he does is displaying it.

Comment: @ddbug, it was in continuation of your comment. The OP has this coded for a generic C library that can be used in other C/C++ projects but hasn't declared the result as `const` data, which may be a problem as I mentioned if the caller tries to modify the result. Certainly it's not a problem for the given ctypes example since the getfunc of `c_char_p` when set as a function `restype` copies the null-terminated result string to Python `bytes` (or `str` in 2.x).

Comment: Caller's dll code is buggy, it returns a const * (and causes memory leak) but his intent is to  return .a writable new'ed buffer.

Comment: @ddbug, I took it at face value that the intent was to do just what it does -- return the string literal "string something". I'd have to guess what the OP is thinking with `char* p = new char [100]`. If it's supposed to be returning a pointer to a buffer that the caller is responsible for freeing, the OP should know that's incompatible with using `ctypes.c_char_p` as the result type. That much would be obvious if the OP didn't have the `restypes` typo.

Comment: @eryksun Well that is silly. I have used ctypes for other functions and did not have the typo. The funny thing is I have been looking at this code for a while and kept missing that. But I fixed that and it seems to work for now. So thank you.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I noticed the other question was not getting responses and I was slightly desperate for help. I will delete the duplicate.

For the record, my goal with this code was to simply get it to return a string. There is a lot I don't know about C/C++ and ctypes, so bear with me. I will take all of your inputs into consideration. Thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you can make an API that does what you are trying to do, you currently will have a memory leak.  A better solution is to have Python allocate and manage the memory for the result.

I also fixed the `dllimport` as mentioned in the comments and defined `TESTLIBRARY_EXPORTS` in the .cpp file so the function would export from the DLL.  `restype` was also fixed.

**TesterLibrary.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef TESTLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define TESTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

TESTLIBRARY_API char* SaySomething(const char* phrase, char* result, size_t resultMaxLength);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**TesterLibrary.cpp**

```
#define TESTLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#include "TestLibrary.h"
#include <stdio.h>

TESTLIBRARY_API char* SaySomething(const char* phrase, char* result, size_t resultMaxLength)
{
    _snprintf_s(result,resultMaxLength,_TRUNCATE,"Decorated <%s>",phrase);
    return result;
}
```

**tester2.py**

```
import ctypes

libName = (r"TestLibrary.dll")
x = ctypes.CDLL(libName)

x.SaySomething.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_size_t]
x.SaySomething.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

phrase = b"Hi"
result = ctypes.create_string_buffer(100)
res = x.SaySomething(phrase,result,ctypes.sizeof(result))
print(res)
print(result.value)
```

**Output**

```
b'Decorated <Hi>'
b'Decorated <Hi>'
```

Python will automatically free the `result` buffer when there are no more references to it.

Comment: @ZachR, if you don't do it this way (which is the simplest and most reliable way), the result type has to change to a `c_void_p` that you cast, or a non-simple pointer type such as `POINTER(c_char)`, or a subclass of `c_char_p`. Otherwise the getfunc of `ctypes.c_char_p` will copy the null-terminated string result to a new Python string object, and you'll have a memory leak. Another complication is that if the caller has to free  memory allocated by the library, then a function for this has to be exported by the library. You can't assume the DLL and Python are using the same C runtime.

Comment: Mark, I will definitely try this. It looks pretty solid. I will get back to you guys on how it goes.
@eryksun Like I mentioned in the above comments there is still a lot I do not know, so thank you for this. I was aware of the memory leak and wanted to get this working before I handled it. I will keep all this in mind when working on this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Worked like a charm! Thanks. And thanks to everyone else too.

Comment: @MarkTolonen this is fantastic thanks, just wondering what should be used, the return value of res or the string buffer itself (result.value), all the memory addresses are different:

`string_buffer C: 0x7fff496c6440
string_buffer Python: 0x7f5f7c85ccb0
return_value Python: 0x7f5f7c88adc0`

My guess is that it doesn't matter as they are both Python objects so the GC will clean up whichever one isn't being used?

Comment: @JackClayton The C source pointer is the same in both cases.  `ctypes` converts the data to a Python `bytes` type.  `bytes` is immutable, so the data has to be copied to create the `bytes` object.  Both are cleaned up by the Python GC with this method.  You don't *need* to return the value if there is an output buffer.  That was for demonstration.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Awesome thanks so much for quick response, are you aware of how something like Numpy is so performant? I wouldn't image it's copying data from C to Python on every operation, is it somehow using pointers in Python to C objects?

Comment: @JackClayton It's not, that's its advantage for large matrix processing.